# Directive priority in Angular not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this element:

`<div ace-editor dl-editor></div>`

And these directives:

```
angular.module('DLApp')


.directive 'aceEditor', () ->
  restrict: 'A'
  priority: 10
  scope: false
  link: linkFunc1

.directive 'dlEditor', (Graph) ->
    restrict: 'A'
    priority: 0
    scope: false
    link: linkFunc2
```

(I'm aware that `0` is the default)

`dlEditor` always gets executed first, then `aceEditor`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to **[the docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)**:
<sub>emphasis mine</sub>

> **priority**
>   When there are multiple directives defined on a single DOM element, sometimes it is necessary to specify the order in which the directives are applied. The priority is used to sort the directives before their compile functions get called. Priority is defined as a number. **Directives with greater numerical priority are compiled first. Pre-link functions are also run in priority order, *but post-link functions are run in reverse order*.** The order of directives with the same priority is undefined. The default priority is 0.

So, the directive with the higher priority (`aceEditor`) is compiled first, but it's post-link function (which seems to be the one of interest to you) is run last.

You should either move the logic in the pre-link function (if that is applicable in your case) or reverse the priorities.

Comment: Really Great answer from @ExpertSystem If I've the chance of voting more than once I'll vote ten times for this note!